# What is a GPX file and what is its use?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

It has been a while now that i have this doubt about Adding **GPX** file to Iphone/iPad project.
What exactly a **GPX** file contains and how does it help us while running app on the *Simulator*.

Comment: check [this](http://gpxframework.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First take a look at [this wiki site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format).

> GPX, or GPS eXchange Format is an XML schema designed as a common GPS data format for software applications.
>   It can be used to describe waypoints, tracks, and routes. The format is open and can be used without the need to pay license fees. Its tags store location, elevation, and time and can in this way be used to interchange data between GPS devices and software packages. Such computer programs allow users, for example, to view their tracks, project their tracks on satellite images or other maps, annotate maps, and tag photographs with the geolocation in the Exif metadata.

and here is an GPX Framework for iOS: http://gpxframework.com/